# What does the command A(~A) really do in matlab

Tags: matlab

I was looking to find the most efficient way to find the non zero minimum of a matrix and found this on a forum :

Let the data be a matrix `A`.

```
A(~A) = nan;
minNonZero = min(A);
```

This is very short and efficient (at least in number of code lines) but I don't understand what happens when we do this. I can't find any documentation about this since it's not an `operation` on matrices like `+`,`-`,`\`,... would be.

Could anyone explain me or give me a link or something that could help me understand what is done ?
Thank you !

Comment: Just a sidenote in case you want to keep this structure: `min` seems to ignore `Inf` more efficiently than `NaN`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It uses [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/)

`~` in Matlab is the not operator. When used on a double array, it finds all elements equal to zero. e.g.:

```
~[0 3 4 0]
```

Results in the logical matrix

```
[1 0 0 1]
```

i.e. it's a quick way to find all the zero elements

So if `A` = `[0 3 4 0]` then `~A` = `[1 0 0 1]` so now `A(~A)` = `A([1 0 0 1])`. `A([1 0 0 1])` uses logical indexing to only affect the elements that are true so in this case element 1 and element 4.

Finally `A(~A) = NaN` will replace all the elements in A that were equal to `0` with `NaN` which `min` ignores and thus you find the smallest non-zero element.

Answer (score 3):

The code you provided:

```
A(~A) = NaN;
minNonZero = min(A);
```

Does the following:

1. Create a logical index
2. Apply the logical index on `A`
3. Change A, by assigning `NaN` values
4. Get the minimum of all values, while not including `NaN` values

Note that this leaves you with a changed `A`, which may be indesirable. But more importantly this has some inefficiencies as you spend time changing `A` and possibly even because you get the minimum of a large matrix. 
Therefore you could speed things up (and even reduce one line) by doing:

```
 minNonZero = min(A(logical(A)))
```

Basically you have now skipped step 3 and possibly reduced step 4.

Furthermore, you seem to get an additional small speedup by doing:

```
 minNonZero = min(A(A~=0))
```

I don't have any good reason for this, but it seems like step 1 is now done more efficiently.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible that `~A` is slower than `A ~= 0` because the former casts to `logical` and then negates.

Comment: @Edric That would indeed make sense. However it turns out that I should not have negated it, and that without the negation it is still slower. Please see my edited post.