# Convert data into binary to use the jaccard similarity coefficient

Tags: matlab, binary-data

So I have a huge 3D array that is a scan of some tissue. I need to be able to replace all non zero entries in this array with 1, and keep all zeros the same. How can I go about this?

Then, once I've done this I need to calculate the jaccard similarity coefficient (JSC) which I can use matlabs built in functions `union()` and `intersect()` , I just need to find a way of finding the number of voxels in the tissue (i.e. if my array is `x`, I need to find `|x|`)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is simple using logical indexing ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102153/what-does-the-command-aa-really-do-in-matlab/18102236#18102236)):

```
I = ~~I;
```

Although it's probably more realistic to set everything above a threshold to 1 and everything below to 0:

```
th = 0.001; %//for example
I = I >= th;
```

So as for the JSC based on wikipedia I'm assuming you're comparing two equal sized binary images? Lets say `I` and `x`:

```
M11 = nnz(I & x);
M10 = nnz(I & ~x);
M01 = nnz(~I & x);
M00 = nnz(~I & ~x);

JSC = M11/(M10 + M01 + M11)
```